# Output of a power-shell command to a variable not working in an if else statement

Tags: powershell

```
$filepath = "c:\InstacartImages\"

$mainDIRoutput = (Test-Path $filepath) | Out-String

if($mainDIRoutput -eq 'False'){
    write-host ("This is the if Statment")
}
else {
    write-host ("This is the else statment")
}
```

It seems every time I run this code it always goes to the else statement when there is or isn't a correct path present.  Not sure what I am missing.

Comment: That's because `Out-String` adds a newline. Remove `| Out-String` and change the `if` condition to just `if($mainDIRoutput)` and it'll work

Comment: Also, this [write-host ("This is the if Statment"))], is really not warranted, this ['This is the if Statment'))], will write to the screen. See additional poorman;s debug effort to illustrate what I am saying.

Comment: Know this about Write-Host as well directly from the creator of Monad/PowerShell Jeffery Snover: [write-host-considered-harmful](http://www.jsnover.com/blog/2013/12/07/write-host-considered-harmful) and [PowerShell v5 Write-Host](https://twitter.com/jsnover/status/727902887183966208).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To elaborate on what @Mathias R. Jessen suggested.
`Test-Path` returns Boolean value of True or False, represented by the corresponding variables `$true` and `$false`. Having said that you may try:

```
if($mainDIRoutput -eq $false){
    write-host ("This is the if Statment")
}
else {
    write-host ("This is the else statment")
}
```

So if `$mainDIRoutput = $false` if would be returned, if `$mainDIRoutput = $true` else will be returned.

I played a bit with `Out-String`, cause it got my attention:

```
$true
True
```

but

```
($true | out-string) -eq 'true'
False
```

as discussed `$true` returns the value of true, which is 4 characters, but if we use `Out-string` it returns 6 chars:

```
($true | out-string).Length
6
```

Just of curiosity I have converted it into ASCII, as the last two symbols were empty:

```
($true | out-string).ToCharArray() | foreach {[int][char]$_}
84
114
117
101
13
10
```

84 = T, 114 = r, 117 = u, 101 = e, 13 = carriage return, 10 = line feed.

If you still need to use string, instead of Boolean values, you may try

```
($true).ToString().length
4
```

and

```
($true).ToString() -eq 'true'
True
```

or in your case:

```
$mainDIRoutput = (Test-Path $filepath).tostring()
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use boolean simply like this :

```
$filepath = "c:\InstacartImages\"

$mainDIRoutput = Test-Path $filepath

if($mainDIRoutput)
{
    write-host ("This is the if Statment")
}
else {
    write-host ("This is the else statment")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a poorman's debug approach by using PowerShell variable squeezing to assign to the variable and output at the same time

```
($filepath = 'd:\temp\')
($mainDIRoutput = Test-Path $filepath | Out-String)
if ($mainDIRoutput -eq 'False') { 'This is the if Statment' }
else { 'This is the else statment' }

# Results
<#
d:\temp\
True

This is the else statment
#>


($filepath = 'd:\temp\')
($mainDIRoutput = Test-Path $filepath)
if ($mainDIRoutput -eq 'False') { 'This is the if Statment' }
else { 'This is the else statment' }

# Results
<#
d:\temp\
True
This is the if Statment
#>


($filepath = 'd:\temp\')
($mainDIRoutput = Test-Path $filepath | Out-String)
if ($mainDIRoutput) { 'This is the if Statment' }
else { 'This is the else statment' }

# Results
<#
d:\temp\
True

This is the if Statment
#>


($filepath = 'd:\temp\')
($mainDIRoutput = Test-Path $filepath)
if ($mainDIRoutput) { 'This is the if Statment' }
else { 'This is the else statment' }

# Results
<#
d:\temp\
True
This is the if Statment
#>
```